# Expo build properties error - couldn't find DSO to loaad

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas, expo-build

I need to set the minSdkVersion of my expo app (with custom dev client) to 24. So, I added the "expo-build-properties" plugin with the minSdkVersion to my app.json file as mentioned [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/):

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "plugins": [
      ...
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
          {
            "android": {
               "minSdkVersion": 24
            }
          }
      ],
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I build the app using `eas build ...`, when I try to run the app on an Android emulator or a physical Android device, I get the following error. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? The only change I made was to set the min sdk version. Everything else remained as before when the app would run properly.

[image]

In case it matters, I am developing on a MacBook Pro with an M1 chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who faces the same issue, I was able to fix the problem by adding a new custom plugin as mentioned in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17450#issuecomment-1248050296):

Basically, first save the plugin code in the post above to a file in your project, for example, `./withAppBuildGradleModified.js`.

Then, in your `app.json` or `app.config.js` file, add the plugin to the plugins array like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "plugins": [
      ...
      "./withAppBuildGradleModified"
    ]
  }
}
```

And finally, rebuild your app using the proper eas build command. If you get any errors during the build, you may need to add `--clear-cache` to your eas build command.

Hope this saves the next person a few hours of uncertainty and doubt :)